"traps: netplan[*] general protection fault ip:* sp:* error:0 in generate[***+*]" Why is it appeared in /var/log/syslog
The system has been appearing this log in the /var/log/syslog sometimes.
Aug  5 11:54:03 hostName snapd[1343666]: storehelpers.go:923: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "certbot", "core18", "core20", "lxd", "snapd"
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName kernel: [82239583.092404] show_signal: 15 callbacks suppressed
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName kernel: [82239583.092408] traps: netplan[1364128] general protection fault ip:558871562f10 sp:7ffe79bbcf00 error:0 in generate[55887155f000+6000]
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1364124]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan terminated by signal SEGV.
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd-udevd[351154]: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno1.link: No valid settings found in the [Match] section, ignoring file. To match all interfaces, add OriginalName=* in the [Match] section.
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core22, revision 1439...
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName dbus-daemon[1021]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.19297' (uid=62803 pid=1364154 comm="/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh --no-metadata-check " label="unconfined")
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core22, revision 1439.
Aug  5 11:54:10 hostName systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1]: snap-core22-1122.mount: Succeeded.
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName kernel: [82239583.902685] traps: netplan[1364201] general protection fault ip:5654d1c72f10 sp:7ffdce771d30 error:0 in generate[5654d1c6f000+6000]
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName fwupd[1364181]: 02:54:11:0423 FuPluginUefi         Error opening directory “/sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries”: No such file or directory
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1364196]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan terminated by signal SEGV.
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName dbus-daemon[1021]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Aug  5 11:54:11 hostName systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Aug  5 11:54:12 hostName systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
Aug  5 11:54:12 hostName systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download activities.
Aug  5 11:54:12 hostName fwupdmgr[1364154]: Fetching metadata https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
Aug  5 11:54:12 hostName fwupdmgr[1364154]: Fetching signature https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc
Aug  5 11:54:12 hostName snapd[1343666]: storehelpers.go:923: cannot refresh snap "core22": snap has no updates available
Aug  5 11:54:13 hostName fwupdmgr[1364154]: Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported
Aug  5 11:54:13 hostName systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded.
Aug  5 11:54:13 hostName systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.

At the same time, it is also showed up in the kernel log /var/log/kern.log
My system is
username@host$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
username@host$ uname -a
Linux hostname 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Can you explain why and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.
I don't get it. I just searching for internet. No clue finding.
